# STM32 Bootloader doesn't work

Tags: embedded, usb, stm32, dfu

I want to write code on STM32F407 board. So I wrote blink example code and complied for it. and then insert binary program in it. After do this, I disconnected usb physically and connected again. But usb doesn't responded. so I opened 'device manager' to see what's happened. STM32 usb connection revealed 'unknown device (device request descriptor failed)'. I did do my best to solve this problem. What solution exist for this problem.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your application is running there will be no USB device present unless your application itself implements a USB stack.  The DFU USB device only exists while actually in the bootloader.  See the *Bootloader code sequence* section in [AN3156](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00264379.pdf).  To enter the DFU you must configure the BOOT0/BOOT1 pins for *System Memory Boot Mode*.

If you have enabled *Read Protection* that will disable SYSTEM and SRAM memory boot modes, and the chip will need unlocking to recover programmability via these methods.

Comment: How to set BOOT pins ? Jumper is already on my board and this STM32 board can't communicate with computer now..

Comment: Without knowing what board you have and its current jumper settings, we cannot tell you, but it is not really in the domain of SO to answer such questions. If you have the jumper set for system memory boot, then some other problem is evident.  I have never used DFU, I use JTAG/SWI and my own boot-loader code in flash for in-field updates - much simpler in the long run IMO.  Consequently  may not be of much help.  However if your blink application is continuing to run, you are not in the DFU mode, and have booted from flash.